# 1.19 brezis . Let $\phi, \psi: E \rightarrow (-\infty, +\infty]$ be two functions such that $\phi\leq \psi$. Prove that $\psi^*\leq\phi^*$.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

1.19 brezis . Let $\phi, \psi: E \rightarrow (-\infty, +\infty]$ be two functions such that $\phi\leq \psi$. Prove that $\phi^*\leq \psi^*$. Where $\phi^*$ and $\psi^*$ are convex conjugate functions.

I started to study convex conjugated function. Would you give me a hint in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what $E$ is or convex conjugate is so i'm using below definition from wikipedia. I hope it is what you want.

[image]

Now if you use the infimum definition you can see that

$$\psi(x)-\langle x,x^*\rangle\geq \phi(x)-\langle x,x^*\rangle$$ for all $x\in E$

Comment: Thank you very much.